Word problem: Every cat in Wonderland is either wise or mad.
Every cat in Wonderland is either wise or mad. If a wise cat happens to be in one room with 3 mad ones it turns mad. If a mad cat happens to be in one room with 3 wise ones it is exposed by them as mad. Three cats entered an empty room. Soon after the 4th cat entered,
the Ist one went out. After the 5th cat entered, the 2nd one went out, etc. After the 2012th cat entered, it happened for the first time that one of the cats was exposed as mad. Which of these cats could both have been mad after entering the room?
(A) The 1st one and the 2011th one
(C) The 3rd one and the 2009th one
(B) The 2nd one and the 2010th one
(D) The 4th one and the last one
(E) The 2nd one and the 2011th one
I dont understand how to work out this question. I guess that one possibility is that the 3 cats inside are wise (for most of the part) and only wise entered, until the last. So the last one is mad?

I suggest:  work this out for smaller numbers than $2012$.

Source: 2012 Kangaroo math contest, grades 11-12, problem 30.

It could even be both wise and mad, if it is Schrödinger's cat (assuming that "wise" means "alive" and "mad" means "dead").

@GeoffreyTrang This is at least the interpretation of this thought experiment. Of course , the cat is either dead or alive , no matter whether we know which is the case.

Your guess is one way the 2012th could be the first one marked, but then none of the answers work.  What happens if the first three cats are mad?  Can you find another way that no other cat gets marked?

Please credit the source where you encountered this problem, in the question.  See https://math.stackexchange.com/help/referencing

The last cat must be wise, so the three possibilities for the last four cats are ...
W-W-M-W or W-M-W-W or W-W-M-W

Up to cat #2011 it must be true that 2 out of every 4 consecutive cats are wise and two are mad, the only ways to accomplish this are alternating singles or alternating pairs i.e. starting with ...
M-W-M-W-M... or  W-M-M-W-W-M... or W-W-M-M-W-W...

or the same thing with W and M interchanged
In each case there is a repeating cycle of length 4, so the pattern for cats 1 to 4 is identical to the pattern for cats 2005 to 2008
case 1 : ending with W-W-M-W (2011 is mad)

must come from alternating pairs with the first 4 being W-W-M-M
none of the options can be satisfied

case 2 : ending with W-M-W-W (2010 is mad)

must come from alternating singles with the first 4 being W-M-W-M
option (B) is satisfied - cats 2010 and 2 are both mad

case 3 : ending with M-W-W-W (2009 is mad)

must come from alternating pairs with the first 4 being M-W-W-M
none of the options can be satisfied

